# create a diagram of composition of functions

Tags: diagrams

How can I draw the following diagram in latex?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I'd be the first to admit that the syntax looks like [line noise](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/L/line-noise.html), but `xy` is very fast and you get nice results.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[arrow]{xy}
\begin{document}
\begin{xy}
     (0,20)*+{A}="a"; 
    (20,20)*+{B}="b";
     (0, 0)*+{C}="c";
     {\ar         "a";"b"}?*!/_8pt/{f};
     {\ar@{>>}    "a";"c"}?*!/^6pt/{g};
     {\ar|{\circ} "c";"b"}?*!/^8pt/{h};
\end{xy}
\end{document}
```

There are a couple of great tutorial papers by Paul Blaga in PracTex [here](https://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/blaga/blaga.pdf) and [here](https://tug.org/pracjourn/2007-1/blaga/blaga.pdf).

Answer (score 6):

Two `pstricks` solutions:

```
    \documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pst-node, auto-pst-pdf}

    \begin{document}

    \psset{arrows=->, arrowinset=0.15, linewidth=0.6pt, nodesep=3pt, labelsep=2pt, rowsep=1.2cm}
   $ \begin{psmatrix}
     A & B \\%
     C
    %%%
     \ncline{1,1}{1,2}\naput{f} %
     \ncline[arrows=->>]{1,1}{2,1}\nbput{g }
     \ncline{2,1}{1,2}\nbput{h}\psset{framesep=-2pt}\ncput*{\pscircle(0,0){3pt}}%
       \end{psmatrix} $
\qquad
   $ \begin{psmatrix}
     A & B \\%
     C
    %%%
     \ncline{1,1}{1,2}\naput{f} %
     \ncline[arrows=->>]{1,1}{2,1}\nbput{g }
     \ncline{2,1}{1,2}\nbput{h}\ncput{\pscircle(0,0){3pt}}%
    \end{psmatrix} $

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Sebastiano's answer is good, but it doesn't replicate *exactly* what is shown above, probably because he was (as he admits himself) in a hurry. Allow me to contribute my answer (by the way, I am in no way trying to degrade your answer, Sebastiano, I'm just trying to help and add some more details). So here's the code in `tikzcd`:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document} 

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=large, row sep=large]
A \ar[d, "g"', twoheadrightarrow] \ar[r, "f"] & B \\
C \ar[ru, description, "h"']
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

But sadly, `tikzcd` *doesn't have* the circle arrow implemented, so I can't do anything. Thruston already showed the solution with `xy` package, so I guess I'm left with plain `tikz`. It is undoubtedly harder but also more flexible than `tikzcd` or `xy`. Here's the final code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, auto]
\node (A) {$A$};
\node(B) [right of=A] {$B$};
\node (C) [below of=A] {$C$};
\draw[->](A) to node {$f$}(B);
\draw[->>](A) to node [left] {$g$}(C);
\draw[->](C) to node [below=0.5ex] {$h$}(B);
\node at (1.0099,-1.002) {$\circ$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear I have only given the input seen because missing also the user MWE. I admit my guilt for the rush but I was hoping that someone appreciated my little work. Personally I vote all positive as I appreciate the help and interest of each of us.

Comment: Yes, I understand. No guilt needed whatsoever. The important thing here is that we got the problem resolved and learned something new ourselves in the process. That's all that matters. Have a good day, sir.

Answer (score 2):

This is a starting point. You could search for symbols with the arrows or `\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}` that you need and the image is made with `tikz-cd`. I did everything in a hurry. Always I have voted negative just because I go always in a hurry? I appreciate every answer and the positive vote independently. I vote a negative response when it is senseless or off topic.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document} 

\[\begin{tikzcd}
    A\ar{r}{f}\ar{d}[swap]{g} & B\\
    C \ar{ur}{h} & 
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, please add a comment explaining the reason for the downvote.